# Recursion versus Iteration using stack in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, linked-list, stack, iteration

**Which is better in terms of memory usage (or in general)?**

1. Using *Recursion* and having stack implementation (OS-implicit)
2. Using *Iteration* and having stack implementation (explicit)

A sample code for a question on Leetcode named [1265. Print Immutable Linked List in Reverse](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-immutable-linked-list-in-reverse/) is given below.

```py
class Solution:
    """Recursion"""

    def printLinkedListInReverse(self, head: "ImmutableListNode") -> None:
        if head:
            self.printLinkedListInReverse(head.getNext())
            head.printValue()


class Solution:
    """Iteration"""

    def printLinkedListInReverse(self, head: "ImmutableListNode") -> None:
        stack = []
        while head:
            stack.append(head)
            head = head.getNext()
        while stack:
            stack.pop().printValue()
```

Please contrast the above code in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

The recursive version of your code takes more memory, because it at least stacks the local variables (and there are two of them: `self` and `head`) and the return address (from where execution should continue after the call).

In the iterative version of your code, the explicit stack only has references of `head`.

The situation would improve if the function were not a *method* of `Solution`, but this is a pattern that is at the heart of the LeetCode testing framework.

Another consideration is that the call stack is limited in size. So if the input is large, then the recursive version is not an option.

Now, this doesn't say anything about the speed of the program. It might still be that the recursive version runs faster, depending on the interpreter.

Comment: I think the recursion has to keep track of a lot more than just two local variables - it also keeps track of the name of the function, the flow of execution, etc.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer, @stef.

Comment: But my answer would be basically identical to yours, except I'd add half a sentence after "because it stacks the local variables and there are two of them". The most important point of your answer is "when you write your own stack rather than using recursion, you can choose what to keep in memory" and I don't have anything else to add to that.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, recursion takes more memory than iteration. See for example

[https://webrewrite.com/iteration-versus-recursion-which-one-you-choose](https://webrewrite.com/iteration-versus-recursion-which-one-you-choose/)

For large datasets I always use iteration.